# Print specific JSON data from Array - JSON conditions

Tags: php, json

I´am calling the API function to get list of active telephone numbers from my provider and I can print the JSON response as follow:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420607659770 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030037243 [iccid] => 8942031013792372436 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420731037691 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030037242 [iccid] => 8942031013792372428 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420732763471 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030037241 [iccid] => 8942031013792372410 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420732788951 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030037244 [iccid] => 8942031013792372444 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420735041563 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030037200 [iccid] => 8942031013792372006 ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778890012 [GsmSubscription] => isActive [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030010134 [iccid] => 8942031013392101342 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778890078 [GsmSubscription] => Suspend [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => 230031030010244 [iccid] => 8942031013392102449 ) 
[7] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897001 [GsmSubscription] => Aging [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[8] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897002 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[9] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897003 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[10] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897004 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[11] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897005 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[12] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897006 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[13] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897007 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[14] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897008 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[15] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897009 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[16] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897010 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[17] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897011 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[18] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897012 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) 
[19] => stdClass Object ( [msisdn] => 420778897013 [GsmSubscription] => [waiting_for_response] => [imsi] => [iccid] => ) ) ) [error] => )
```

So if this is the complete response, than I can select specific data I need, which is the "msisdn" number in this case:

```
foreach($result->response->msisdn as $value)
 {
$msisdnnumbers = $value->msisdn;
```

By this PHP echo, I have the list of "msisdn" numbers from JSON reponse.

But now, I would like to add some conditions. For example, I would like to echo only the "msisdn" numbers where the field of "GsmSubscription" contain the value "Suspend". Is it possible with PHP to add this condition?

Comment: Your question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong then you have to use `if` condition

```
foreach($result->response->msisdn as $value)
 {
  if($value->GsmSubscription === 'Suspend'){
    $msisdnnumbers[] = $value->msisdn;// to get an array of values
  } else {
    continue;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes using PHP condition, that´s what I looked for...thanx